# How to stop loading browser page in selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mozilla

I am using seleninum web driver in c# and facing a weird problem.
While automating i encountered a problem where page is continuously loading although DOM content has been loaded. Now i have now way to go forward until it does not stop, that why driver throws timeout exception.
So, I need to know is there any way to stop page load from webdriver.

I have googled but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things. Use Actions class press ESC key to stop the page from loading, Code shown bellow:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(Driver);
actions.SendKeys(Keys.Escape);
```

Or User JavaScriptExecutor to do the samething:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("return window.stop();");
```

Comment: @Saifur you might need to call `stop`: `((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("window.stop();");`

Comment: I have tried above both but the problem is selenium will not proceed next command until page is loading.

Comment: @SirajHussain Explain the result with StackTrace and stuff like that. I use it for testing and works for me

Comment: Siraj Hussain is right in that this never works right after the statement webdriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("something"); and the page is still loading. Please refer to my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012586/how-to-stop-loading-page-in-selenium-webdriver-when-an-element-is-already-presen