# pageLoadTimeout is not working in Selenium - Java

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, pageloadtimeout

I am testing a website in linux host.The page i am accessing loads infinitely so I am trying to set pageLoadTimeout for selenium.
Firefox is triggered correctly but URL is not loading/navigating/added in url bar.just blank firefox window.I am not seeing any errors also.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.example.com");
```

However if I remove `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` code is working fine

Selenium version : 3.14.0;

gecko driver : 18 - linux (tested with gecko 16,17 also same issue)

browser : firefox-52

os/platform : linux

If this kind of some issue how do I make sure my driver quit itself after 5 minute.Host will support only firefox 52.

I checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591282/pageloadtimeout-in-selenium-not-working) but doesnt fix my problem.

Thanks
Jk

Comment: Based on a comment in your supplied link, this appears to be a known, and not yet resolved issue.  Perhaps go with implicit wait instead?

Comment: Since it is infinitely loading i am not getting the control back on code.It just stuck on driver.get

Comment: @BillHileman Do you still see an issue within the example provided in the discussion for which OP supplied the link? I can explain further.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for help . As i mentioned when i add driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS); driver.get("url") is not even hitting the URL. Timeout is working  in mac + firefox61+geck21 . So i feel there is some issue in firefox-linux combination. So looking for alternative to that command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the pageload strategy for browser which will then make the page not wait for the full page load for your other Selenium commands to be executed. Below is the sample code snippet in Java. There are three supported values:

**normal**

This stategy causes Selenium to wait for the full page loading (html content and subresources downloaded and parsed).

**eager**

This stategy causes Selenium to wait for the DOMContentLoaded event (html content downloaded and parsed only).

**none**

This strategy causes Selenium to return immediately after the initial page content is fully received (html content downloaded).

By default, when Selenium loads a page, it follows the **normal** pageLoadStrategy.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("pageLoadStrategy", "eager");
FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
opt.merge(caps);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(opt);
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

If you are interested only in the HTML of the page, better use the "eager" strategy.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned the *url* you are trying to access but **pageLoadTimeout** for *Selenium* works as expected with With **Selenium v3.14.0**, **GeckoDriver v0.23.0** and **Firefox Quantum v62.0.3** combination. I am able to see the expected output on the console with the following example which prints **TimeoutException occurred. Quiting the program** whenever the **pageLoadTimeout** is triggered:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

  import org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

  public class A_Firefox_Test 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          System.setProperty("god.bless.us", "C:/Utility/BrowserDrivers/geckodriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          try {
              driver.get("https://www.booking.com/hotel/in/the-taj-mahal-palace-tower.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaGyIAQGYATG4AQbIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKSAgF5qAID;sid=338ad58d8e83c71e6aa78c67a2996616;dest_id=-2092174;dest_type=city;dist=0;group_adults=2;hip_dst=1;hpos=1;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;srfid=ccd41231d2f37b82d695970f081412152a59586aX1;srpvid=c71751e539ea01ce;type=total;ucfs=1&#hotelTmpl");
          } catch (TimeoutException e) {
              System.out.println("TimeoutException occurred. Quiting the program.");
          }
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  1539157195615   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 1920
  Oct 10, 2018 1:09:56 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
  INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
  Oct 10, 2018 1:10:00 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
  INFO: HTTP Status: '500' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'timeout' (408 expected)
  TimeoutException occurred. Quiting the program.
  ```
- You can find the detailed stack trace in [pageLoadTimeout in Selenium not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591282/pageloadtimeout-in-selenium-not-working/45648881#45648881)
- You can find the *Pythonic* approach to `pageLoadTimeout` in [How to set the timeout of 'driver.get' for python selenium 3.8.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47694922/how-to-set-the-timeout-of-driver-get-for-python-selenium-3-8-0/47695227#47695227)